# fft in python not showing peaks in right place

Tags: python, fft

I'm trying to understand the numpy fft function, because my data reduction is acting weirdly. 
But now that I've transformed a simple sum of two sines, I get weird results. The peaks I have is extremely high and several points wide around zero, flattening the rest. Does anybody have a clue of what I might be doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, sqrt, pi, linspace
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import pylab


#fourier
tdata = np.arange(5999.)/300
datay = 3*np.sin(tdata)+6*np.sin(2*tdata)
fouriery =  np.fft.fft(datay)

freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(datay.size, d=0.1)


pylab.plot(freqs,fouriery)
pylab.show()
```

What I get is this:
[image]
While it should have two sidepeaks on both sides, one of em 2x higher than the other

Comment: Can you upload a photo of the resulting graph to your answer? And perhaps a graph of what it "should" look like?

Comment: Done, can't make a "how it should look" graph, as I don't have anything that could do that. But it should have 2 peaks on the left and right and have a lot lower amplitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your `datay` is real, so perhaps you should be taking a FFT for a
  real sequence using `scipy.fftpack.rfft`.
- If you are looking for an FFT with two distinct peaks, then you must
  give it data which is the sum of sine waves whose terms have periods
  which are whole multiples of `2*pi/n`, where `n = len(datay)`. If not, it will take many such sine
  waves to approximate the data.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack

pi = np.pi
tdata = np.arange(5999.)/300
datay = 3*np.sin(2*pi*tdata)+6*np.sin(2*pi*2*tdata)
fouriery = fftpack.rfft(datay)
freqs = fftpack.rfftfreq(len(datay), d=(tdata[1]-tdata[0]))
plt.plot(freqs, fouriery, 'b-')
plt.xlim(0,3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. But how about the amplitude, that still seems to be very large for reasons I don't understand. Oh and why are they negative?

Comment: [The Fourier Transform of a sine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformSine.html) is a sum of delta functions. The sine is distributed in space, and highly localized in frequency-space. The delta function has mass at only one point, but integrates to one, so it is thought to have "infinite" amplitude. The discrete Fourier transform which we are computing here is sort of an approximation of the Fourier transform, so it makes some sense that the amplitudes should also be very large and localized, like the delta function.

Comment: I don't have an intuitive explanation for why the amplitudes are negative.

Comment: By the way, it is a general principle that functions that are localized in space are distributed in frequency-space, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but with normal fourier transforms they should have different amplitudes (and be positive). Which is my problem, as I need to fit a powerspectrum to an theoretical curve and keep missing it by exactly a factor of 1000.

Comment: Different people define fourier transform different ways, often varying by factors involving 2, pi and `N`. You'll probably have to go back to the [definition scipy.fftpack.rfft is using](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.rfft.html) and compare it to the definition used in the theoretical curve you are fitting. `N/(2*pi)` is about 1000, so that might be the source of the discrepancy.